# error in perform searching using cloud firestore in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I am having issues in getting the search result. I have some data in cloud `firestore`, I want to perform searching on that data. Here is the screen shot of data, but when I search, I am not able to get any data.

[image: here is the data on which i want to perform searching]

and here is the code ...

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:reminder/searchservice.dart';

class MySearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MySearchPageState createState() => new _MySearchPageState();
}

class _MySearchPageState extends State<MySearchPage> {
  var queryResultSet = [];
  var tempSearchStore = [];

  initiateSearch(value) {
    if (value.length == 0) {
      setState(() {
        queryResultSet = [];
        tempSearchStore = [];
      });
    }

    var capitalizedValue =
        value.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + value.substring(1);

    if (queryResultSet.length == 0 && value.length == 1) {
      SearchService().searchByName(value).then((QuerySnapshot docs) {
        for (int i = 0; i < docs.documents.length; ++i) {
          queryResultSet.add(docs.documents[i].data);
        }
      });
    } else {
      tempSearchStore = [];
      queryResultSet.forEach((element) {
        if (element['email'].startsWith(capitalizedValue)) {
          setState(() {
            tempSearchStore.add(element);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: Text('Search Here'),
        ),
        body: ListView(children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (val) {
                initiateSearch(val);
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: IconButton(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                    iconSize: 20.0,
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0),
                  hintText: 'Search by Email',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0))),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          GridView.count(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
              primary: false,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: tempSearchStore.map((element) {
                return buildResultCard(element);
              }).toList())
        ]));
  }
}

Widget buildResultCard(data) {
  return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
      elevation: 2.0,
      child: Container(
          child: Center(
              child: Text(data['email'],
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              )
          )
      )
  );
}
```

and here is the code of service...

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class SearchService {
  searchByName(String searchField) {
    return Firestore.instance
        .collection('task')
        .where('title',
        isEqualTo: searchField.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase())
        .getDocuments();
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: noting happend when i type any thing

Comment: I think the question title is misleading if there is no error.

Comment: ok i am changing it

Comment: can you please read the code and tell me what is the actual issue ? @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 1):

I guess your error is in the `.where` clause.

This's a very wired condition

`.where('title', isEqualTo: searchField.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase())`

And it match only if you have a title of 1 capital letter corresponding to the first letter you have searched. So I bet your `docs.documents.lenght` is 0.

Read carefully Cluod Firestore [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) section.

1. You can use a simple query like that:

> ```
> .where('title', isGreaterThan: searchField)
> ```

2. Or if you want a more complex indexed search you could try [composite indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing).

[Index overview](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview)

3. But if you wanna do more inference on your search string (e.g. contains, etc.) you have to query first and then filter here:

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < docs.documents.length; ++i) {
>     //TODO: do more sofisticated filtering here
> }
> ```

4. Or, if you would, you can create an *additional `task field`* and you populate this value with a "search string" prebuild by you and made up in such a way that the basic Cloud Firestore queries should return what you want.